# String from backend should contain emoji but is rendered as accented letters

Tags: php, ios, cocoa-touch, encoding, nsstring

I have an issue receiving a string from a PHP backend into my iOS app. The string I receive looks like this:

> Test ððððð

Those special characters should be smileys. Now I checked with this encoder here:
https://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php
and the string is UTF-8 encoded indeed the one with smileys.

> Test

Now I wonder what encoding is the source string? And how can I convert it to an UTF-8 string that displays correctly on iOS?

I've tried

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"Test ððððð" options:0];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and

```
NSString *message = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"Test ððððð", CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

and also

```
NSString *message = [@"Test ððððð" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but none of those worked. I kind of baffled what the source string is encoded like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably nothing wrong with your Foundation app (which, by the way, natively supports UTF-8 & UTF-16 very, very well).

---

#### To answer your last question:

> I'm kind of baffled what the source string is encoded like.

If you crack open that string and take a look at it in terms of bytes, you'll notice that the eth character ('ð' [Icelandic and Faroese use this character]) is UTF-8 codepoint `0xf0`.

`0xf0` is also the beginning of a UTF-8 surrogate sequence to begin encoding the Emoji character '' above (0xf0, 0x9f, 0x98, 0x80). The rest of the 3 bytes for the Emoji are lost.

#### [TL;DR]

Something in your backend, maybe PHP itself, isn't supporting Unicode very well.

Comment: Actually, it was "broken content" in the database. I tested to display only the last message that was entered via the phone and that showed the smileys. Then I added all other messages and then it got broken. Seems there was some weird data in the table.